# How to share screenshot on fb with unity without uploading image?

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, share

so i'm trying to share a screenshot on fb and i tried everything and the only thing i got working doesnt makes me happy :c, i ll explain!

Here's how it's working right now:

```
   Texture2D screenTexture = new Texture2D(Screen.width, Screen.height, 
   TextureFormat.RGB24, true);

    screenTexture.ReadPixels(new Rect(0f, 0f, Screen.width, Screen.height), 0, 0);

    screenTexture.Apply();

    byte[] dataToSave = screenTexture.EncodeToPNG();

    var wwwForm = new WWWForm();
    wwwForm.AddBinaryData("image", dataToSave, "itsadisaster.png");

    FB.API("me/photos", HttpMethod.POST, ShareCallback, wwwForm);
```

The problem is, that in this way the app/facebook ask for permission to post and that isn't cool! Other thing is that on this way the user can't write on the post its just the picture automaticaly!

I tried this way too:

```
ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot("ss.png");
            string imagePath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/ss.png";


        FB.FeedShare(
            new System.Uri("https://google.com.br/"),
            new System.Uri(imagePath),
            ShareCallback
        );
```

And after a little research i got that feedshare only works with images that are posted on internet that i would get by an url like "www.blablabla.com/ss.png".

But i want the user to see the post and the image that he will post so he can write "i want to see who can score more than me!!!" and then post with the ss picture!

Is it possible to be done? Please help

Comment: How could you share something without uploading it? Isn't that an important step?

Comment: The first method i posted works fine, i just needed to include the byte[] var that it's the image. The second one im giving the file path, the FB method should upload by itself i guess like in the first one

Comment: It simply doesn’t work that way, there is no image upload possible for link posts. And you can not even specify the link thumbnail at the time of sharing any more - all additional info is only taken from the OG meta tags the shared URL returns.

Answer (score 1):

By the newest SDK(facebook-unity-sdk-7.10.1) example for ios I can capture screenshot and upload to FB directly. SDK will help to create a new FB photo album named as your App name and publish photo to timeline. I did following steps:

1.build SDK example to iphone.

2.press "FB.init" button

3.press "Login" button and accept permission.

4.press "Get public_actions" button. (important)

5.press "Graph Request" button

6.press "Take and Upload screenshot".

7.check out your FB.

the [page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.API) said: Take and publish a screenshot (requires publish_actions), requires version 4.3.3 or later. So the code in step 4 is asking the "publish_actions" permission. The key code is:

**FB.LogInWithPublishPermissions(new List() { "publish_actions" }, this.HandleResult);**

also [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.LogInWithReadPermissions) explain why the code as public_actions permission later.

Comment: Unfortunately "publish_actions" was deprecated: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/04/24/new-facebook-platform-product-changes-policy-updates/

Comment: Yes they have change it recently, thanks for the update.